# How can I display in view multiple GridViews with one DataProvider group it by some field?

Tags: yii2

A have a table 'operations' with finance operations for all users, including 'id', 'user_id', 'sum', 'name', 'date_picked' etc.

I have created one ActiveDataProvider that gets all operations for concrete User. Now I would like to display in view data from this dataprovider - not in one GridView, but in several GridViews which data grouped by 'date_picked' value.

I know that I can make a new dataprovider for the each 'date_picked' but there will be a large amount of requests to database.

Is there a way to display grouped data in several GridViews based on one dataprovider's data?

```
Controller:
/** @var OperationComponent $comp */
$comp = Yii::$app->operation;
$userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
$filterModel = $comp->getOperationSearch();
$operations = $comp->getSearchProvider($userId, Yii::$app->request->get());

OperationComponent:
public function getOperationSearch()
{
    return new OperationSearch();
}

public function getSearchProvider($user_id, $params)
{
    $model = new OperationSearch();
    return $model->search($user_id, $params);
}

OperationSearch:
public function search($user_id, $params)
{
$query = Operation::find();

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 10,
    ],
  // сортировка по умолчанию
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'date_picked' => SORT_DESC
        ]
    ]
]);
return $dataProvider;

View:
....
<?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $filterModel,
.....
]); ?>
....
```

Comment: You can make a separate ```GridView``` on demand. E.g. when the user enters ```date_picked``` the depending ```GridView``` is build or updated.

Comment: @WeSee thank you for the reply, but I need that after initial load user saw data for the period (e.g. week or month) separated by days.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Yii2 extension for complex GridViews: [kartik-v/yii2-grid](http://demosbs3.krajee.com/grid)

It contains collapsible rows for showing details for a row.

You can view a demo [here](http://demosbs3.krajee.com/grid-demo).

What you are looking for is the [Expand Row Column Widget](http://demosbs3.krajee.com/grid#expand-row-column). It allows to expand a row by just loading the required data for this row details.

This extension has a good documentation is quite stable and tested and can be used straight forward.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll check the widget. Thank you very much!